# kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: not implemented AlertDialog

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I was trying to practice a little with desktop compose for kotlin and when i was trying to implement `AlertDialog` element I got this exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0 @coroutine#3" kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: not implemented

The code that im trying to run :

```
fun main() {
    var text = mutableStateOf(0F)
    var num = mutableStateOf("a")
    Window(
        size = IntSize(500, 500),
        title = num.value,
        menuBar = MenuBar(
            Menu(
                name = "Test",
                MenuItem(
                    name = "Dodaj random",
                    onClick = {
                        text.value = text.value + Random.nextFloat()
                        if (text.value > 1F) {
                            text.value = 0F
                            num.value += "a"
                        }
                    },
                    shortcut = KeyStroke(Key.A)
                ),
                MenuItem(
                    name = "Exit",
                    onClick = {
                        AppManager.exit()
                    },
                    shortcut = KeyStroke(Key.L)
                )
            )
        )
    ) {

        MaterialTheme {
            Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp)) {
                LinearProgressIndicator(text.value.toFloat(), modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally))
                val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        openDialog.value = true
                    }) {
                    Text("Click me!")
                }
                if (openDialog.value) {
                    AlertDialog(
                        onDismissRequest = { openDialog.value = false },
                        title = { Text("Dialog title") },
                        text = { Text("Here is a text") },
                        confirmButton = {
                            Button(
                                onClick = {
                                    openDialog.value = false
                                }
                            ) { Text("Confirm butt") }
                        },
                        dismissButton = {
                            Button(
                                onClick = {
                                    openDialog.value = false
                                }
                            ) { Text("Diss butt") }
                        }
                    )
                }
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        text.value += 0.1F
                        if (text.value > 1F) {
                            text.value = 0F
                            num.value += "a"
                        }
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                ) {
                    Text(text.value.toString())
                }

                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        num.value += "a"
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                ) {
                    Text(num.component1())
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Only when I'm trying to click on the "Click me" button I'm getting this exception other buttons works perfectly.

My imports

```
import androidx.compose.desktop.AppManager
import androidx.compose.desktop.Window
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.LinearProgressIndicator
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.input.key.Key
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntSize
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.window.KeyStroke
import androidx.compose.ui.window.Menu
import androidx.compose.ui.window.MenuBar
import androidx.compose.ui.window.MenuItem
import kotlin.random.Random
```

Comment: Just tested and works fine. What JDK version are you using? Can you please also add your imports?

Comment: Added imports, I'm using JDK 11.0.6

Comment: Hmmm everything looks fine. Which version of Jetbrains Compose are you using?

Comment: 0.1.0-m1-build62
I don't really know what is happening everything besides this works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue seems related to [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/issues/81) github issue.

To solve it simply update compose dependency to 0.2.0-build132.

Complete example of my build.gradle with the correct versions:

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.compose

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.20"
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "0.2.0-build132"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
    }
}
```

Comment: When i did what u said i got this `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass, but class was expected`

Comment: You have something weird in your Gradle file, can you post it?

Comment: I've added my build.gradle file so you can compare if there are any dififerences

Comment: Thanks you very much, when i changed jvm version from "1.4.0" to "1.4.20" it started working